# opening ibm .phd files using visualVM

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-dump

Can some one please tell me how to open the .phd(IBM Portable heap dump) files in VisualVM ?
I have tried with Heap Analyser to open it but I could not locate exactly which object is causing the issue ?

Comment: I had out of memory all the time opening a .phd file. I tried increasing the heap size of of MAT multiple times and finally i had to set it to 10GB to get it done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files can be opened easily using IBM Heap Analyzer. download it from here ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/websphere/appserv/support/tools/HeapAnalyzer/ha456.jar.

For @Lyiju question on the question comment, that's normal, start from the command prompt specifiying the max heap size as below

```
"<JAVA_PATH>\Java.exe" -Xms256m -Xmx6144m -jar <HEAP_ANALYSER_NAME>.jar
```

Comment: Having tried Eclipse MAT, Eclipse + Health Monitor, this application is the best. It did not start for me on openj9 vm, after initial start on hotspot vm then it was able to run on openj9